# There is an error saying "Cannnot post/". I do not know how to deal with this

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

As the reference to the subject, I have been stuck the problem. I can also see a strikethrough on the name of const, "bodyParser" as the photo shows. I do not know whether it works well or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`bodyParser` middleware is deprecated. You can use the built in middleware in express. In your code (you should include code as text instead of image), there aren't POST "/" route, so the error Cannot POST "/" is expected.

You can refer to this example to set up a POST route.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.listen(3000);
```